# Magento 1.9.x Inovice PDF Customization

Tags: magento-1.9, invoice, pdf

I am using the Firegento PDF extension on a Magento CE 1.9.3.0 Store. By law (Germany) we need to have specific notes on the pdf invoices regarding tax.

For every invoice within the EU, there should be a note saying

`Dies ist eine steuerfreie innergemeinschaftliche Lieferung`

For every invoice outside the EU, there should be a note saying "Dies ist eine steuerfreie Ausfuhrlieferung".

How can I set it up? I cant set notes for specific countries.

I couldn't get this to work: [Add note on invoices for specific countries](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/43366/add-note-on-invoices-for-specific-countries)